# How to stop a cron job from subsequent runs after an error

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

What different practices exist for preventing a cron job from running again if it exited unsuccessfully after its last run?

Is using a lockfile appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a lock file is the simplest solution.